# Logging in a centralised way

Tags: python, logging

I have 2 independent scripts in which I use the logging module. When running them, I would like to keep the logs in a centralised way, in the sense of having a single folder for all of them. These are the scripts:

foo.py

```
import logging


def foo():
    logging.info('MY INFO AUX IN FOO')
```

bar.py

```
import logging


def bar():
    logging.info('MY INFO AUX IN BAR')
```

How could I set up a YAML file that told the scripts to store the logs in the same place? Any ideas/best practices are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `logging.config` to read from configuration file.

```py
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('/path/to/logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

```
# logging.ini
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("/path/to/log/file.log",)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s - %(levelname)s:%(message)s
```

For more detail, please check this tutorial [How to collect, customize, and centralize Python logs](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/python-logging-best-practices/#use-fileconfig-to-output-logs-to-multiple-destinations)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by using [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), creating your own logging file.

```py
with open(logfile,'a+') as f:
    f.write(loginfo)
```

Or you could use the built-in function in [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to specify a filename.

Like so:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile)

logging.info('MY INFO AUX IN FOO')
```

Comment: So, your proposal would be to create a directory somewhere in my local disk for the logs and store there the logs like foo.log, bar.log etc, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, whether you do that (create the directory/file) using ``open`` or ``logging`` is up to you. EDIT: The file need not be local, it can be anywhere where a path is resolvable.